# Put SESSION variable in variable and use it global

Tags: php, session, variables, global-variables

I am working on a project where a save data in session variables. It is a Wordpress project where I use the function "sd_wizard_glass_type" to show this as a template on a page in my website.

As you can see: I first put $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype'] in the variable $glasstype.

Then if $_GET['glasstype'] is set I put it in $glasstype. And now I can use $glasstype everywhere in my function "sd_wizard_glass_type" (as a session variable).

But now I want to use the variabe $glasstype ($_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']) In the following function (in the following wordpress page) and that doesn't work. But If I use $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype'] on the page is does work.

Is there something I can do to use $glasstype as the session variable?

```
// Step: Glass type
function sd_wizard_glass_type() { 

    $glasstype = $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype'];

    if(isset($_GET['glasstype'])) :
        $glasstype = $_GET['glasstype'];
    endif;
}
```

Last Update:

```
function sd_wizard_glass_type() { 

    if(isset($_GET['glasstype'])) :
        $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype'] = $_GET['glasstype'];
    endif;

    $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype'] = $glasstype;
}
```

Comment: `$_SESSION` is already global.

Comment: Yeah I know, but for some reason I cannot use $glasstype global, which is the session variable $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']

Comment: Are you trying to use `$glastype` outside of the scope of the function?

Comment: Yes that's what I am trying

Comment: @Robbert then write it back into the session, as I have shown in my answer.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Watch my latest update in my question. Tried that but does not work..

Comment: Of course not, `$glasstype` is never initialised. Remove the last line and you should be OK. And read a decent tutorial about how PHP variables work.

Comment: No because then I can't use $glasstype anymore. I had written down $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype']; everywhere but I wanted to use $glasstype for a cleaner code. But I think this only works if I use $glasstype in this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a couple of things you can try. first, if you need the variable to persist between pages, then sticking it in the session is a good idea. if you ONLY need it to live on that single page, then you can use parameters and return values to move it around. for example

```
function sd_wizard_glass_type() { 
    if(isset($_GET['glasstype'])) :
        $type = $_GET['glasstype'];
    else
        $type = $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype'];
    return $type;
}

$glasstype = sd_wizard_glasstype();
```

now glasstype is set outside of the function

if you need to pass glasstype back into a function

```
function newfunction($glasstype)
{
    //stuff
    //return something;
}
```

and then call it the same way

```
$foo = newfunction($glasstype);
```

you can also use the key word `global` to make a variable global, but that won't persist beyond the given page

edit: the main thing to know here is variable scope in php. if you declare a variable inside a function, you can't use it outside of the function. if you declare it outside  a function, you can't use it inside functions UNLESS you either use the global keyword or pass it as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

> And now I can use $glasstype everywhere in my function "sd_wizard_glass_type" (as a session variable).

No. This is a local variable. When you do

```
$glasstype = $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype'];
```

you copy the *value* of the session variable into a local variable.

Session variables can be set by putting them in the `$_SESSION` superglobal:

```
$_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype'] = $glasstype;
```

Answer (score -3):

Use pointer:

```
$glasstype = &$_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype'];
```

BUT if you try:

```
function toto()
{
    $glasstype = &$_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype'];
    $glasstype = 42;// Work
}
toto();
$glasstype = 42*42; // Fail because $glasstype is a local var
// If you want to do this, replace all $glasstype by $_SESSION['showerdoor']['glasstype'].
```